# Can Qt's QWebView display programmatically generated XML?

Tags: c++, xml, qt, webkit, qwebview

Using Qt 4.6, I can dynamically add to an HTML page like this:

```
ui->webView->page()->mainFrame()->documentElement().findFirst("body").appendInside("<i>some text</i>\n");
```

However, if I QWebView::load() an XML file, it displays it with the correct CSS styling (from an  processing instruction), but doesn't show any changes when I do something like:

```
ui->webView->page()->mainFrame()->documentElement().findFirst("lines").appendInside("<line>hello</line>\n");
```

Why is it treating them differently, and is there a way to modify an XML document in the same way I can an HTML one?

Answer (score 0):

Try using setUrl() rather than load(). If that magically works it's a bug.

Comment: That doesn't work. I'm just going to use HTML instead of XML.

Comment: That's probably best if you can swing it. I think this might be Qt not handling the differences between styled XML and (X)HTML. It could be that some of the core assumptions for this object are wrong for XML.

Out of curiousity have you tried ui->webView->page()->mainFrame()->findFirstElement rather than using the documentElement?